# File contents remains in terminal after exiting Vim?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, vi, zsh

I'm using the stock terminal with zsh and vim. After I exit vim, the file contents remains in the terminal. Ideally, only the previous history would be in the terminal when I exit vim (such as the behavior I've seen with linux/bash).

How can I accomplish that?

**Update**

I'm running os x Yosemite 10.10.1

I tried glenn jackman's suggestion below, but still no dice.

Additional information:

`echo $TERM` produces `ansi`

I also tried in bash with the same results.

I also tried removing `.vimrc` completely with the same results.

Comment: Weird. On my Lion system, running vim under zsh nets the usual exit, i.e., the file contents are not visible.

Comment: Try setting `TERM=xterm` in the shell before opening vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

Similar to glenn jackman's solution, I added

```
if &term =~ "ansi"
    let &t_ti = "\<Esc>[?47h"
    let &t_te = "\<Esc>[?47l"
endif
```

to my `.vimrc` file (notice the `ansi` instead of `xterm`).

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
if &term =~ "xterm"
    let &t_ti = "\<Esc>[?47h"
    let &t_te = "\<Esc>[?47l"
endif
```

to your `~/.vimrc`

Ref: https://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=3431